# Chrome extension grab active DOM from 'inspect element'

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

There are hidden elements that show up in the DOM when I use 'inspect element', i.e. a div with style='display: none'. These elements do not show up in the DOM when I grab the source of the page using `sendResponse(document.all[0].outerHTML);`  To clarify, I *am* getting the DOM but not including the hidden elements, though the hidden elements show up in the 'inspect element' screen.

What is the proper way to get exactly the same information as I see in the inspection screen of Chrome?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle or some code? `document.all[0].outerHTML` should do the job fine.

Comment: I don't know what other information you need. `document.all[0].outerHTML` spits out the DOM, of course, but is missing elements that are set to hidden but which are visible when I use 'inspect element' feature of Chrome. How to I get these elements? I want to get the exact same information as when I inspect element.

Comment: Are you using the [shadow dom](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/)?